# How to integrate OTP authentication into existing JSecurity Login?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, jboss

I have a pure JavaEE application (EJB Jars and Web Archive)
The WAR according Java EE security defines the j_security_check action for login forms (FORM Based Authentication)

If userId and password entered use existing standard password authentication module which redirected to j_security_check.

I would like to integrate OTP to increase security and login using userId and otp but the j_security_check mechanism in Java EE containers is primarily designed for traditional username and password-based authentication, and it doesn't directly support otp authentication method.

Server : Jboss Application Server v4.0.5
Java EE 7 - Servlet/Jsp

OTP based Login:
If user select otp based login and click on generte otp button then OTPGenerator class generate a new OTP and store it in a cache associated with the user's username. Afterward, the OTP can be sent to the user's registered phone number.

on Login click, the CustomOTPCheckModule retrieves the stored OTP for the user and verifies it against the provided OTP.

How to acheive below step please suggest.

If the OTP is valid, bypasses the standard password authentication and completes the login process and redirects the user to the appropriate destination page.

Thanking in advance.